How to specify anchor in AdvancedMarkerElement?
Since support for google.maps.Marker ends on February 21, 2024, we are considering migrating to google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement.
I replace the marker icon with an image, but I don't know how to specify the anchor.
In the Google sample below, the anchor of beachflag.png seems to be at the bottom left (0, 32), but the anchor is displayed at the bottom center.
Create markers with graphics 
With google.maps.Marker, I can specify the anchor as shown below, but how do you specify the anchor with AdvancedMarkerElement?
let icon = {
   url: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png",
   size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
   origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
   anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32), //bottom left
 };
 
let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: position,
     map: map,
     icon: icon
 });


Marker clickable arae
enter image description here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505618/google-maps-api-custom-marker-anchor-points/78330775?noredirect=1#comment138787613_78330775
May be the second answer will help

See issue this issue in the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/292069884
adding this: beachFlagMarkerView.content.style.transform = 'translateX(44%)' works for me (doesn't look quite right with 50%)
beachFlagImg.src =
    "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png";

const beachFlagMarkerView = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
  map,
  position: { lat: 37.434, lng: -122.082 },
  content: beachFlagImg,
  title: "A marker using a custom PNG Image",
});
beachFlagMarkerView.content.style.transform = 'translateX(44%)'

As @tibalt indicated in the comments, you can also use css margin to control the icon's position:
beachFlagImg.src =
    "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png";

const beachFlagMarkerView = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
  map,
  position: { lat: 37.434, lng: -122.082 },
  content: beachFlagImg,
  title: "A marker using a custom PNG Image",
});
beachFlagMarkerView.content.style.marginLeft = '16px';


proof of concept fiddle
code snippet using transform:


async function initMap() {
  // Request needed libraries.
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary(
    "marker",
  );
  const { Place } = await google.maps.importLibrary("places");
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 37.434, lng: -122.082 },
    zoom: 13,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
  });
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  // A marker with a with a URL pointing to a PNG.
  
  var measle = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: 37.434, lng: -122.082 },
    map: map,
    optimized: false, 
    icon: {
      url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
    }
  })
  const beachFlagImg = document.createElement("img");
  

  beachFlagImg.src =
    "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png";

  const beachFlagMarkerView = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
    position: { lat: 37.434, lng: -122.082 },
    content: beachFlagImg,
    title: "A marker using a custom PNG Image",
  });
  beachFlagMarkerView.content.style.transform = 'translateX(44%)';
  // A marker customized using a place icon and color, name, and geometry.
  const place = new Place({
    id: "ChIJN5Nz71W3j4ARhx5bwpTQEGg",
  });
}

initMap();
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Advanced Markers Using Graphics</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js"></script>

    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- prettier-ignore -->
    <script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "beta"});</script>
  </body>
</html>



code snippet using css margin


async function initMap() {
  // Request needed libraries.
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary(
    "marker",
  );
  const { Place } = await google.maps.importLibrary("places");
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 37.434, lng: -122.082 },
    zoom: 13,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
  });
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  // A marker with a with a URL pointing to a PNG.
  
  var measle = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: 37.434, lng: -122.082 },
    map: map,
    optimized: false, 
    icon: {
      url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
    }
  })
  const beachFlagImg = document.createElement("img");
  
  beachFlagImg.src =
    "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png";

  const beachFlagMarkerView = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
    position: { lat: 37.434, lng: -122.082 },
    content: beachFlagImg,
    title: "A marker using a custom PNG Image",
  });
  beachFlagMarkerView.content.style.marginLeft = '16px';
  // A marker customized using a place icon and color, name, and geometry.
  const place = new Place({
    id: "ChIJN5Nz71W3j4ARhx5bwpTQEGg",
  });
}

initMap();
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
<!doctype html>
<!--
 @license
 Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Advanced Markers Using Graphics</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js"></script>

    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- prettier-ignore -->
    <script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "beta"});</script>
  </body>
</html>




Thank you for your quick reply.
It looked right.
but Marker click event are fired even outside the pin.
It seems that the range of gmp-advanced-marker element is targeted.
Is there any solution to this problem

The hack that not work in many cases... for example with InfoWindows.

Instead of translate use negative margin, then parent div will follow the child marker. Otherwise you will have a transparent parent that will catch clicks in the wrong place.
